# No understanding Why i cant access dm_crypt-0 -> LVM2_Member

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, encryption

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu server with encryption. However from the looks of it I am unable to access the majority of the space. I believe its not mounted to a directory but it shows as mounted because the root directory. How can I either mount the 3.6T to /home or extend the root to use the whole disk space?

```
$ lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                         7:0    0    73M  1 loop  /snap/core22/607
loop1                         7:1    0  73.9M  1 loop  /snap/core22/817
loop2                         7:2    0   163M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/24643
loop3                         7:3    0 173.5M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/25112
loop4                         7:4    0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/18596
loop5                         7:5    0  53.3M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/19457
nvme0n1                     259:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1                 259:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                 259:2    0     2G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3                 259:3    0   3.6T  0 part  
  └─dm_crypt-0              253:0    0   3.6T  0 crypt 
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:1    0   100G  0 lvm   /
```

result of trying to mount:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0 /mnt/Cloud/
mount: /mnt/Cloud: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

```
$ $ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 72.99 MiB, 76537856 bytes, 149488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 73.86 MiB, 77443072 bytes, 151256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 163 MiB, 170917888 bytes, 333824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 173.46 MiB, 181882880 bytes, 355240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 49.84 MiB, 52260864 bytes, 102072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 53.26 MiB, 55844864 bytes, 109072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: CT4000P3PSSD8                           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 57C945BD-62AC-47B7-B0B3-2481E5CB4230

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    2203647    2201600    1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 2203648    6397951    4194304    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 6397952 7814033407 7807635456  3.6T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0: 3.64 TiB, 3997492576256 bytes, 7807602688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: `lvcreate` to make a new volume or `lvextend` to grow an existing one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole 3.6T encrypted partition has been assigned to be managed by LVM, but only 100G of it has been actually allocated for use as your root partition.

You can't mount the `/dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0` directly, because it has been initialized as a *LVM physical volume* (PV for short) which acts as a container for one or more *LVM logical volumes* (LVs for short), each of which can contain a filesystem (or something else, like a swap partition or a raw database, if you wish).

The advantage of LVM over traditional partitions for you is that it allows you to create multiple logical volumes, and still extend them without having to care about whether there is free space to the "right" of them, like with traditional partitions. You can even extend those logical volumes on-line, while the system is running.

If you add another disk later, you can add it to the same *LVM volume group* (VG for short) with the existing one, and then use the disk space of both disks as one large pool. You could allow a filesystem to be extended beyond the limits of any single disk, if you need to.

There are three commands that are useful to display LVM status and available space:

- `sudo vgs` displays your LVM volume group(s), their attributes, total size and the amount of free (unallocated) capacity, which you can use for extending existing LVs or creating new ones as you wish.
- `sudo lvs` displays the attributes and size of each LVM logical volume.
- `sudo pvs` displays information on your LVM physical volume(s): the device path, the volume group it belongs to, its attributes, size and how much of it has been allocated. (This can be important if you are planning an on-line *data migration*: using `pvmove` you can move entire filesystems from one PV to another while the filesystem is in use.)

**Note:** by default, Ubuntu has named your initial volume group as `ubuntu-vg` and the logical volume that contains your root filesystem `ubuntu-lv`. There are two ways to refer to the logical volumes as devices:

- the old way (from before the 2.6.x kernels): `/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`
- the unified Device-Mapper way: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

When using the Device-Mapper style paths, any dashes in the VG and LV names need to be doubled, as a single dash is used as a separator between the VG and LV names. **This only applies when using the names as part of a `/dev/mapper/...` device path:** when using a VG or LV name alone as a parameter to some LVM command or its option, the dash-doubling is not required.

For example, to extend your current root filesystem to 200G, you could run just one command:

```
sudo lvextend -r -L 200G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

If you want to create a separate `/home` filesystem, you could make a new logical volume for it with:

```
sudo lvcreate -n home-lv -L 1T ubuntu-vg
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-home--lv  # or whatever filesystem type you wish
```

Note that mounting your new filesystem to `/home` will be rather difficult unless you can login directly as root, since your existing home directory will be at `/home/<username>` and if you are logged as a regular user, it will be in use. Mounting another filesystem to `/home` would hide your home directory under the new filesystem, temporarily preventing access to it by any new logins.

Note that while you can extend many filesystem types while the filesystem is mounted and in use, *shrinking* a filesystem can be more difficult, or practically impossible as in case of XFS filesystems (so far). So, when using LVM, it can be useful to err on the low side when allocating disk space, since you can easily extend filesystems as long as you have unallocated LVM space to do so.

Comment: Very epic answer! Thank you for that education. I will be adding a HDD to the system for long storage so the bit about extending to that LVM is very useful.

Comment: To do that, you will need two commands I did not mention yet: `pvcreate`to initialize a partition (or even a whole disk) for use by LVM, and then `vgextend` to add the newly initialized PV into the volume group. This will add more unallocated space to the VG, which you can then use by extending existing LVs and/or creating new ones, any way you want.